# Closing multiple forms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I have three forms in my application.
Form1, Form2, and Form3.

Form1 opens Form2 and they are both open.  This is OK.  I want this to happen.

Form2 has a button that opens Form3.  Again, this is desired behavior.

Form3 has two buttons... One that closes Form3 and goes back to Form1 and Form2 being open.  I can do this one.

The problem is the second button on Form3...  I need that button to close Form3 and Form2 so that only Form1 is now open.

Any ideas on how to close multiple forms at a time without closing the application?

Comment: Make a Boolean property in Form3, attach to Form 3's FormClosing event in Form 2. Check the property close Form2 if it is true, else do nothing and let Form3 close.

Comment: Hmya, why is there a button?  What's supposed to happen when the user uses the normal way to close a window?  Why can't you use form3's FormClosed event in form2?  Why haven't you shown at least an *attempt* at making it work so we don't have to prompt you for info like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a list of all Forms in the [Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx) collection that are **not** of type Form1; then close them:

```
    private void btnCloseAllExceptForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Form> formsToClose = new List<Form>();
        foreach(Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (!(frm is Form1))
            {
                formsToClose.Add(frm);
            }
        }
        foreach(Form frm in formsToClose)
        {
            frm.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This could be much simpler: `Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(x => !(x is Form1)).ToList().ForEach(frm => frm.Close());`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, absolutely.  If you're comfortable with LINQ syntax then it makes more sense to do it that way.  Most beginners don't get it, though...  =)

Comment: Also, I'm thinking what happens if there are multiple instances of `Form1`, only one of which is the main form of the application. `ApplicationContext` has a `MainForm` property. Is there any way to get the current `ApplicationContext`?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can have a local reference to the `Form2` that opened the specific `Form3` and pass it in Form3's constructor:

```
//references the Form2 that opens me (this is Form3)
private Form2 MyForm2Instance;

//you can add this in your existing Form3's constructor, or create a new one
public Form3(Form2 frm2)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyForm2Instance = frm2;
}
```

Then in your Form3's button you can have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this will close only the Form2 that opened this Form3
    //and it will also close this Form3
    MyForm2Instance.Close();
    this.Close();
}
```

Now all you need is to change the way you open your Form3, by using the new constructor from Form2:

```
Form3 frm3 = new Form3(this);
frm3.Show();
```